# Инициализация переменной в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо инициализировать переменную и присвоить ей значение, которое хранит один из столбцов таблицы. Потом надо проверить, равно ли это значение переменной 11.
Пытаюсь сделать таким образом:

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE Functions @codes  INT
      AS
         DECLARE @ans INT;
         SET @ans = SELECT [Код ответа] FROM [SofI].[dbo].[Журнал] WHERE 
         [Код сеанса] = @codes AND [Код вопроса] = 11

          IF (@ans = 11)
              exec FunOther
```

Это наверное глупо, но я не знаю как иначе, даже не знаю как иначе (без использования переменной) проверить условие равенства. Так тоже нельзя:

```
      IF ((SELECT [Код ответа] FROM [SofI].[dbo].[Журнал] WHERE [Код сеанса] 
      = @codes AND [Код вопроса] = 11) = 11)
```

Как можно сделать проверку?

Comment: Чем плох первый кусок кода?

Comment: Пишет, что "Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "SELECT"."

Comment: Если удалить конструкцию перед Select, а именно ...SET @ans = ...
То всё скомпилится

Comment: оберните все что после "CREATE PROCEDURE Functions @codes  INT
      AS" в BEGIN ..... END, и возьмите ваш SELECT целиком в скобки

Comment: Спасибо, Вы правы!

Comment: @Anna Прошу обратить внимание на дополнение к ответу - поможет упростить логику вашей процедуры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

правильный и безопасный синтаксис вашей процедуры будет таким:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Functions @codes  INT
      AS
         DECLARE @ans INT;
         SET @ans = (SELECT top 1 [Код ответа] FROM [SofI].[dbo].[Журнал] WHERE 
         [Код сеанса] = @codes AND [Код вопроса] = 11);

          IF (@ans = 11)
              exec FunOther
```

`top 1` в селекте нужен для обеспечения нормальной работоспособности, когда после изменения данных таблицы ваш запрос вернет 2 значения.

---

P.S. Для решения текущей задачи можно было бы воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [SofI].[dbo].[Журнал] 
           WHERE [Код сеанса] = @codes AND [Код вопроса] = 11 
                 AND [Код ответа] = 11)
    exec FunOther
```

Comment: Коллега, в первом решении не хватает ORDER BY 1 DESC, иначе ваш запрос так и будет работать с одним значением

Comment: @NickProskuryakov Спасибо за комментарий, но в данном случае стоит защита только от сиквельной ошибки присвоения интовой переменной набора, ваше дополнение предполагает еще одно дополнительное вмешательство в бизнес-логику, о которой мы не имеем ни малейшего понятия. Только автор вопроса может определить, какой порядок сортировки применить в запросе.